# Use openssh proxyjump to connect to database

Tags: psql, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I have the following network configuration

```
localhost -> proxy -> databaseserver
```

I'm using [OpenSSH ProxyJump](https://medium.com/maverislabs/proxyjump-the-ssh-option-you-probably-never-heard-of-2d7e41d43464) to establish a cli ssh connection from my localhost to the databaseserver without having to deal with an explicit tunnel. It works fine !
Here's a sample configuration of my ssh/config file

```
[me@localhost] cat .ssh/config
Host databaseserver
User user
HostName databaseserver_ip
ProxyJump user@proxy
[me@localhost] $ ssh user@databaseserver
[user@databaseserver] $
```

There's no hint about databaseserver's ip in my localhost's /etc/hosts file

What I am trying to achieve is to use ProxyJump with psql (or any other graphical software) in order to avoid creating a dedicated ssh tunnel. ie :

```
[me@localhost] $ psql -H user@databaseserver
```

But that does not work at all ! databaserver is unknown to the psql software. It does not seem to consider .ssh/config content.

Is there a way to run a proxyjump connection with something else than the ssh command ?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem and I'm afraid the answer is no, it is not possible to force `psql` to use the SSH configuration.

#### Alternatives

##### Server-side PSQL

If you are happy to run `psql` on a remote server instead of (or in addition to) your local machine, you might want to use the following syntax:

```bash
ssh -t your-proxy \
  psql -h database-server \
    -U user db-name
```

Because you are invoking SSH locally, it does take your local SSH config into consideration but the fact `psql` is actually running on the server may or may not be what you want. E.g. if you wanted to read or write some SQL files, they would be interacted with on that remote box, not your local machine.

##### GUIs

A little off-topic but I have also tried a few GUI applications: [Postico](https://eggerapps.at/postico2/), [PgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org) and [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) and I've only had success with the latter. It actually explicitly mentions reading the config file in the SSH Configuration modal:

[image]

It's worth mentioning the other two GUI apps I've tried require an SSH tunnel to achieve the same outcome. And also, please note, DataGrip requires a commercial licence to run.